# Set location on Google map on iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm basically implementing a functionality where after a user moves the map a button appears, and when the button is selected a new search happens in visible area. The problem is the visible area is not accurate, so when I try to zoom into it again it zooms out.

every time I click the button the function below is called and the map zooms out. I understand that not calling `animate` and removing the code will avoid the zoom, but I want to know why the zoom is happening, because this may cause problems elsewhere

```
@IBAction func updateSearchSelected(sender: UIButton) {
    let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mapView!.projection.visibleRegion().farRight.latitude, longitude: mapView!.projection.visibleRegion().farRight.longitude)
    let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mapView!.projection.visibleRegion().nearLeft.latitude, longitude: mapView!.projection.visibleRegion().nearLeft.longitude)
    print("northEast \(northEast)")
    print("southWest \(southWest)")
    let coordinateBounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
    let cameraUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(coordinateBounds)
    mapView?.animate(with: cameraUpdate)
}
```

Here are the logs after clicking the button 3 times

```
northEast CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.84227633765466, longitude: -122.38477706909181)
southWest CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.674750313908689, longitude: -122.50391006469727)

northEast CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.859492217765393, longitude: -122.37251903861761)
southWest CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.657491381296779, longitude: -122.51616809517145)

northEast CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.880245733530728, longitude: -122.35773839056492)
southWest CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.636675535472314, longitude: -122.53094874322414)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the zoom level to what you want it to be when you call `GMSCameraPosition.camera` , for example:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.8683,
                                      longitude: 151.2086,
                                      zoom: 16)
```

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views#using_gmscameraupdate

See the section titled *Camera Position*:

"The map view is modeled as a camera looking down on a flat plane. The position of the camera (and hence the rendering of the map) is specified by the following properties: latitude/longitude location, zoom, bearing and viewing angle."

Comment: This won't work I think because I don't know the zoom level, I know the bounds. The API returns bounds and I need to correctly showing the bounds

Comment: So just decide on an arbitrary zoom level, and keep it at that zoom level so it doesn't zoom out whenever you update.

Comment: That doesn't work either it should zoom if it's needed to show the entire content :(